# Recent Chrome changes to getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, getelementsbyclassname

So while writing an IIFE API I realized that chrome has changed the `getElementsByClassName` DOM property. For some reason they've made it harder to get the items we wanted before. for example

```
 [item: function, namedItem: function]
   0: div.sceditor-group
   1: div.sceditor-group
   2: div.sceditor-group
   3: div.sceditor-group
   4: div.sceditor-group
   5: div.sceditor-group
   6: div.sceditor-group
   7: div.sceditor-group
   8: div.sceditor-group
   9: div.sceditor-group
   length: 10
   __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

This is what is logged in the console. Though I can no longer do this

```
 var a = document.getElementsByClassName('sceditor-group');
 console.log(a.length);
 //OR THIS
 for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    //manipulate each element
    //since i now returns 0 for some reason
 }
```

Though if we look at the returned array/object or whatever this may be now. It has a length. So how do we now get the length property!!

**IIFE actual bit**

```
 var t = getElement('class','sceditor-group');
    console.log(t);
    console.log(t.length);
    this.groups = {};
    for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
      this.groups[i] = t[i];
    }
    this.groups.length = t.length;
```

**getElement function**

```
function getElement(t, ele) {
        switch (t) {
        case "id":
            return document.getElementById(ele);
        case "class":
            return document.getElementsByClassName(ele);
        case "element":
            return document.getElementsByTagName(ele);
        case "input":
            return document.getElementsByName(ele);
        case "query":
            return document.querySelectorAll(ele);
        }
    }
```

** response **

```
[item: function, namedItem: function]
  0: div.sceditor-group
  1: div.sceditor-group
  2: div.sceditor-group
  3: div.sceditor-group
  4: div.sceditor-group
  5: div.sceditor-group
  length: 6
  __proto__: HTMLCollection

  0 

  Object {length: 0}
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Why don't you think it still works?

Comment: This is a standard Javascript API, I doubt Chrome would change it to violate the spec.

Comment: Don't forget that `getElementsByClassName` returns a _live_ NodeList. That means if you change the DOM, the contents of `a` will change.

Comment: Well I've tried it 100 times now @Barmar and it's not working. Supposedly the specs for DOM4 are changing or something? Everytime I log the information from said `a` it gives me the first response above, but cannot reach length. Though inside the console it returns a regular array -_-

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 36.0.1985.103 beta. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/88aXL/1/

Comment: It's very odd for me though... I'll show you my responses

Comment: Try turning off extensions and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Didn't help, but found a lot of third party installed extensions -_-

Comment: Unless someone else can reproduce the problem, I don't see how we can help you. It seems like something is messed up in your Chrome, it's not a general problem.

Comment: I tried doing typeof t and it returns `object`  
Chrome: 35.0.1916.153

Comment: That's what it returns for me, too. What do you think it should return instead?

Comment: if you'd like to see the rest of the code http://jsbin.com/ratiwoqi/1/edit please go ahead and review to find the bit just click CTRL+F and write Barmar. oh nevermind, I wasn't using my own type function which returns array if array...etc my bad :) it's an object Array